# TikZ 3.0: How to "scale" a graph layout?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this state machine:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs, graphdrawing, quotes, automata}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}
\tikz[>=stealth, shorten >=1pt] {
  \graph[simple necklace layout, nodes = {state}, node sep = 1cm, grow=right] {
    a[initial, initial text={}],
    b, c, d[accepting], e, f,
    a
    ->["$a$"] f
    ->[loop above, "$a$"] f
    ->[bend left, "$b$"] e
    ->[bend left, "$a$"] f,
    e
    -> ["$b$"] d
    -> ["$a, b$", loop right] d,
    c
    ->["$b$"] d,
    c
    ->["$a$", bend left] b
    ->["$a$", loop below] b
    ->["$b$", bend left] c,
    a
    ->["$b$"] b
    ;
  }
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Automat]

I want to "flatten" the graph layout to make it oval, but without scaling the whole picture (since this messes everything up). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Since `simple necklace layout` places the nodes on a circle, I don't see an easy way to do this with that layout.

Answer (score 3):

The nodes can be moved via option `yshift`. Nodes `f` and `e` go downwards and `b` and `c` upwards:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs, graphdrawing, quotes, automata}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}
\tikz[>=stealth, shorten >=1pt] {
  \graph[simple necklace layout, nodes = {state}, node sep = 1cm,
grow=right] {
    a[initial, initial text={}],
    b[yshift=5mm], c[yshift=5mm], d[accepting],
    e[yshift=-5mm], f[yshift=-5mm],
    a
    ->["$a$"] f
    ->[loop above, "$a$"] f
    ->[bend left, "$b$"] e
    ->[bend left, "$a$"] f,
    e
    -> ["$b$"] d
    -> ["$a, b$", loop right] d,
    c
    ->["$b$"] d,
    c
    ->["$a$", bend left] b
    ->["$a$", loop below] b
    ->["$b$", bend left] c,
    a
    ->["$b$"] b
    ;
  }
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or with some more evenly spaced nodes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs, graphdrawing, quotes, automata}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}
\tikz[>=stealth, shorten >=1pt] {
  \graph[simple necklace layout, nodes = {state}, node sep = 1cm,
grow=right] {
    a[initial, initial text={}],
    b[yshift=5mm, xshift=1.5mm], c[yshift=5mm, xshift=-1.5mm],
    d[accepting],
    e[yshift=-5mm, xshift=-1.5mm], f[yshift=-5mm, xshift=1.5mm],
    a
    ->["$a$"] f
    ->[loop above, "$a$"] f
    ->[bend left, "$b$"] e
    ->[bend left, "$a$"] f,
    e
    -> ["$b$"] d
    -> ["$a, b$", loop right] d,
    c
    ->["$b$"] d,
    c
    ->["$a$", bend left] b
    ->["$a$", loop below] b
    ->["$b$", bend left] c,
    a
    ->["$b$"] b
    ;
  }
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

For this case, I was able to find a workaround using the `layered layout`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs, graphdrawing, quotes, automata}
\usegdlibrary{layered}


\begin{document}
\tikz[>=stealth, shorten >=1pt] {
  \graph[layered layout, nodes = {state}, level sep = 1cm, sibling
  distance = 2cm, grow=right] {
    a[initial, initial text={}] -!- {
      b -!- {
        c
      },
      f -!- {
        e
      }
    } -!-
    d[accepting],

    a
    ->["$a$"] f
    ->[loop above, "$a$"] f
    ->[bend left, "$b$"] e
    ->[bend left, "$a$"] f,
    e
    -> ["$b$"] d
    -> ["$a, b$", loop right] d,
    c
    ->["$b$"] d,
    c
    ->["$a$", bend left] b
    ->["$a$", loop below] b
    ->["$b$", bend left] c,
    a
    ->["$b$"] b
    ;
  }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this will be more tricky with an odd number of vertices. Also, this layout does not let me control the node distance directly. But I'm satisfied.